# Where can I find the black crusaders horse barding?

Tags: shopping, accessories, castle

The question is all in the title. I'm talking about [this](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Castle?file=Castle_Proto_U.png): the *second knight* from the left entrance to the castle.

Answer (score 3):

Good places to find parts include:

- Thrift stores, car boot sales, jumble sales. Sometimes you get lucky.
- eBay is a good general source for parts... as long as you can find what you're looking for.
- [LEGO](http://lego.com)'s [Pick-a-Brick](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Pick-A-Brick-ByTheme) (PAB) service is good for for common parts.
- LEGO's [replacement parts service](https://service.lego.com/en-gb/replacementparts/#BasicInfo) is better for less common parts from newer sets. The range of parts is far greater than PAB, but doesn't come close to being complete.
- [BrickLink](http://www.bricklink.com/), the most comprehensive resource for parts on the internet.

Given that the part you're looking for is older, I suggest that BrickLink might be your best bet.

I couldn't identify the exact part that you wanted, but they do list a good [range of horse barding](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=horse%20barding).

Comment: I have tried all of the above, to no avail. I'm talking about a *non-commercial* barding, one that has never been in store.

Comment: Then, to be honest, you probably can't buy it anywhere.

Comment: @The Lego Company. Hear this desperate cry!